# Arduino autorestarts when powered externally

Tags: arduino-uno

I'm trying to finish  building an alarm system with relays, leds  and bluetooth. I finally made it working but when externally powered (12v source) after about 10 seconds it starts to reboot continuously. 
This issue comes with no pc connection.

Comment: And how toasty does the 5v regulator get...?

Comment: Very much, could be this a sort of heat protection?

Comment: Most regulators have thermal protection, yes. You will need a better power supply arrangement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardUno

Majenko has a good lead,

12V is just within spec of the voltage regulator.

Though this may be different per manufacturer or different in your environment.

To battle overheating you can:

- Create beter airflow
- Add a heatsink
- Draw less current

But you should try a 9V source, that can deliver enough current (not the 9V "block" batteries).

Also check if the system draws excessive current, maybe the circuit has a low resistance or power hungry part (on the 5V rail)

If nothing works, you could try and use another Arduino board, maybe the regulator is faulty/damaged.

Comment: I added an additional power supply 5v for the sensors, relays, etc. Now the arduino regulator is cooler and I don't experience reboots anymore.
Thank you Paul